# Tool for modeling ER diagram and import in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, uml, er-modeling

Is there any tool for ER modeling and then converting models to a Microsoft SQL Server database?

The tool should has this features:

- ER Diagrams shoud be in UML Notation (see [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/ERD_Representation.svg), the last is UML notation).
- Export models to a Microsoft SQL Server 2005/2008 database (by creating a mdf file or connecting to a MSSQL Server and creating suitable database in it).

I tried Microsoft Visio but seems not support UML Notation nor Exporting to MS SQL Server.
I also tried Visual Paradigm but i'm not sure i could export models to MS SQL Server.

Comment: Just curious, why UML notation instead of standard E/R notation like IDEF1X, Chen or IE?

Comment: @Data Monk - This ER model is a part of bigger project and project manager wants any documentation in UML format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I DID export my ER Model to SQL Server database with **[DB Visual Architect](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/dbva)** (a product of from Visual Paradigm family).

**DB Visual Architect** can export ER model to MSSQLServer/MySQL/...

It also let me to convert a **ER Model** to a **class diagram** that is identical to a UML notation.

However, it's not free.

anyway, Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following Microsoft Reference

[When All You Want is an ER Diagram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224825%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you accept commercial software, there are some choices:

1. Upgrade to [Microsoft Visio Professional](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/fx101757911033.aspx) - it supports UML and database modelling
2. [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/)
3. [Power Designer](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner)- my preferred tool for working with ER diagrams.
4. [ErWin](http://www.ca.com/us/data-modeling.aspx)

There are many variants, e.g. many choices listed [here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/modelling_tools.htm).

Comment: I'm not sure the Visio is the best choice, but it supports reverse engineering (as asked in question).

Comment: Visio 2010 does not support UML for ERD.  It can generate diagrams, but not in UML format.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer ERD diagrams for databaser data models. [SQL Power's data architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect)is great for that, and it supports any RDBMS (through JDBC). It does not support UML though.

http://mysql.com/products/workbench/ does support some UML notation, but generates MySql Specific SQL. You can write a plugin for it to generate other SQL dialects

Comment: So these two solutions are not the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

**[Visual UML](http://www.visualuml.com/)**  can:

- UML
- Database reverse engineering
- Database forward engineering -- generate DDL scripts.

If you want to directly connect and generate DB and sync models (forward/reverse) try:

- **[Erwin](http://www.ca.com/us/data-modeling.aspx)**  (no UML)
- **[Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad-data-modeler/)**   (no UML)

Answer (score 0):

You can use my online database code-generator to generate SQL Server DDL Scripts (and Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL,...) from UML models. Instead of forcing you to use a specific UML tool to draw the models, several UML tools are allowed (including Microsoft Visio but also ArgoUML, Eclipse UML,...).

See http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml2db-full-code-generation-sql-scripts-databases

for more information

Answer (score 0):

I remember answering a similar question but cannot find it right now. I advised using [DIA](http://dia-installer.de/download.html) with SQL to DIA found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sql2dia/)